# Bootstrap dropdown menu - display second bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a Bootstrap 3 `navbar` with the out of the box `dropdown-menu` functionality

Is there a way to have a second navbar which is displayed/transitioned on the `dropdown-toggle` of the button? We would like to have the nicely formatted

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
```

with our sub-menu items displayed. Similar to how the [www.bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk) site works when you click the "More" button - the second centralised navbar is displayed rather than the `dropdown-menu` (and hidden when the button is pressed again)

Comment: Please share with us the code that you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) provides you different built-in components that you can use according to your needs.

It has a [Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) component as well that can be used to open and close a block when we click on some specific element.

You can use this component inside `.navbar` and inside `.collapse` body of this component you can use more `.dropdown` items if you want.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-menu">
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <div class="well">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for more than just one dropdown in Bootstrap 3, that's not supported naively.  However, you *can* make it happen.

Here's some example HTML markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                         <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                             <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-submenu-toggle">Second Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                 <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu Item</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu Item</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu Item</a></li>
                             </ul>
                         </li>
                         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /container -->
    </nav>
```

Now, let's let CSS do most of the heavy lifting and use as many native Bootstrap classes as we can.  Just add this custom CSS to your stylesheet, after Bootstrap's main stylesheet.

```
/* NEW 2nd-Level Dropdown CSS START */
.dropdown-submenu{position: relative;}
.dropdown-submenu .caret{-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); transform: rotate(-90deg);}
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {top:0; left:100%; margin-top:-6px; margin-left:-1px;}
.dropdown-submenu.open > a:after{border-left-color:#fff;}
.dropdown-submenu.open > .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu.open > .dropdown-menu {display: block;}
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu{margin-bottom: 8px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu ul{background-color: #f6f6f6;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu ul{background-color:#333;}
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu > li > a{padding-left: 30px;}
@media screen and (min-width:992px){
    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu{margin-bottom: 2px;}
    .navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu > li > a{padding-left: 25px;}
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu ul{background-color:#fff;}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu ul{background-color:#fff;}
} /* END New 2nd-level Dropdown CSS */
```

That CSS takes us 99% of the way.  Now we just need a little Javascript to take us across the finish line.

```
// Make Dropdown Submenus possible
$('.dropdown-submenu a.dropdown-submenu-toggle').on("click", function(e){
    $('.dropdown-submenu ul').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
// Clear Submenu Dropdowns on hidden event
$('#bs-navbar-collapse-1').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $('.navbar-nav .dropdown-submenu ul.dropdown-menu').removeAttr('style');
});
```

That's pretty much it.  Did a little downloadable live demo at: http://demo.jdmdigital.co/wp-bootstrap-navwalker-multilevel/ and [wrote a little article](https://jdmdig.it/2zOp3OF) about using this same code to enable this functionality in your Bootstrap menus when using the WordPress menu system.

Comment: I had to remove `$('.dropdown-submenu ul').removeAttr('style');` to make the sub-menu toggle-able in mobile.

Comment: And how to get the mobile based dropdown in iPad ? I don't want the desktop version of the dropdown in iPad.

Comment: Thanks for the example! If one would want unlimited nested submenus, how would the code be then?

Comment: If you wanted unlimited, nested dropdowns @KevinLindmark, I would suggest writing or using someone else's navigation markup/scripts.  There are lots and many are a lot prettier than what comes with Bootstrap.  Here is a really cool example: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/